# Putty use local internet proxy for remote machine

Tags: port-forwarding, putty

Is there a way you can use your local internet proxy for remote computer with tunneling via SSH. My machine has access to internet via proxy. But the remote computer does not. I don't have admin rights there. Here is the schematic :

```
Internet   Internet
   /\         /\
   ||         ||
  proxy       XX
   ||         ||
   \/         \/
   A<---SSH--->B
```

What I think I need to do is I have to remote port forward to a local port then forward that port to my proxyurl. What settings should be done in putty to make this work. Can anyone help.

Comment: Do you have admin rights anywhere in this ?

Comment: No, dont have admin rights in A or B.

Answer (score 1):

Yes(ish): OpenSSH supports SOCKS4/SOCKS5 compatible proxying, via [the `-D` option](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1).

Putty also [supports this](http://www.virtualroadside.com/blog/index.php/2007/04/12/dynamic-socks-proxy-using-putty/) -- Look under the "Tunnels" option in the tree menu you get when you launch Putty and you should see an option for dynamic port forwarding. [This is also described in the Putty documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/puttydoc.txt).

Note however that you may have issues proxying through a host that itself is going through a proxy ("Try it and see!").